# PHPMailer sending e-mails with the warning: This message may not have been sent by: foo@gmail.com Learn more Report phishing

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send automated e-mails from my website and while testing, I noticed that all e-mails sent by php mailer are generating the following warning on the recipients end:

This message may not have been sent by: foo@gmail.com  Learn more  Report phishing

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this?

PHP Mailer code:

```
//mail functions
require("mailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require("mailer/class.smtp.php");
require("mailer/class.pop3.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  
$mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
$mail->Port = 25;  
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "foo@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "pass"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "foo@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "FOO";
$mail->AddAddress("fOO@gmail.com", "WIDB");
$mail->AddReplyTo("foo@gmail.com");
//$mail->AddAddress("foo@gmail.com");                  // name is optional

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
//$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");         // add attachments
//$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");    // optional name
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Foo - Transaction Receipt';
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = "nothing";

//send mail
$mail->Send();
```

I am using GMail and I have SMTP enabled...

Comment: That's not coming from your PHP server, it's coming from the email recipient's email host because the IP address of your server doesn't match any of google's (a.k.a. your SMTP server).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not sure I understand the problem:/ Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Make sure the server you're sending the mail from is the same as the supposed "from" address. Don't use a "from" address from *google.com*. If you have a server with a URL set up, use that URL. Your email host is trying to prevent phishing attacks which sometimes use address spoofing.

Comment: So basically, If I changed the FROM address to a hotmail address, the phishing warning would go away? and I can still provide a reply-to e-mail address that is a g-mail address, correct?

Comment: Well, no. That will give you the same problem - the address that the email is ACTUALLY coming from is not hosted on any of gmail or hotmail's servers. You'll still get the anti-spoofing message.  It's safe to ignore it until you get a proper email host set up, though.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! :) I am using godaddy for hosting, is there a way for me to find out what the 'actual' server im sending the mail from, through them?

Comment: It needs to come from YOUR DNS-registered URL. So, for example, if your site is at *www.emailspoofer.com* it needs to come from *noreply@emailspoofer.com* or another address, as long as it's from *emailspoofer.com*. Even then, it may not work if all your email settings aren't correct. Try using an email library (there are a few open-source APIs out there).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either set up google apps for your site and get a Username@yourwebsite.com gmail account ([more info here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/) it's free), or You will need to set up an e-mail address on your current server that is Username@yourwebsite.com and use that as the $mail->from address.

Your E-Mail recipients are receiving the message because you are telling google to send an e-mail from your server, and then you are telling them that the mail is coming from gmail, which it isn't, it's coming from your personal server. Since the from address and your server address don't match, they flag it as spam. This is googles way of preventing spam, to them it would be the same if you put $mail->from(YOURMOM@LOL.com). The e-mail would still send, but your domain name does not match the @ address.

Comment: I am running a drip marketing project where the emails go from a single server and the send mails can be from any of the emails entered by the user. Can there be any solution for this as irrespective of the client email, the mail is send from a single SMPT emial protocols and get that same error as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from following the above guidelines, here something I noticed that might help someone.

When I sent an email with body "Please check the attached work order" and a pdf attachment, gmail showed it with a spam warning(inside inbox)

When I sent an email with body "Your work order has been attached" and the same pdf attachment, gmail didn't show any warning.

I'm using java api for sending emails