# PHP mail sender authentication warning

Tags: php, email

I am sending mail from my hosting server through this PHP code :

```
mail("myemail@gmail.com", "Subject: Verify Eg Net Solution ID", $randStr , "From: Egnetsolution@gmail.com" );
```

In `myemail@gmail.com` the email is send but there is a warning that is saying :

```
"This message may not have been sent by: Egnetsolution@gmail.com  Learn more  Report phishing"
```

[image]
What I have to do in my hosting domain server. I will really appreciate you if you can give me a solution.

Comment: who vote it down. I am in trouble don't fun .

Comment: Make sure that SMTP authentication is set to true.

Comment: Use @mail() to hide errors. What you're doing is definitely "phishing" as you could be simply scripting a mass mail.

Comment: You can not vote down the question for an silly error , I am a novice. As much I know a voted down user can not ask more question in stack over flow @pratiknagariya . You should change your mind to soft for the novice.Should make path for little boy, don't should n't destroy their road.

Comment: I have not voted down your question.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow please can you tell in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726820/phpmailer-sending-e-mails-with-the-warning-this-message-may-not-have-been-sent):**

> You can either set up google apps for your site and get a
>   Username@yourwebsite.com gmail account ([more info here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/) it's free), or
>   You will need to set up an e-mail address on your current server that
>   is Username@yourwebsite.com and use that as the $mail->from address.
>
> Your E-Mail recipients are receiving the message because you are
>   telling google to send an e-mail from your server, and then you are
>   telling them that the mail is coming from gmail, which it isn't, it's
>   coming from your personal server. Since the from address and your
>   server address don't match, they flag it as spam. This is googles way
>   of preventing spam, to them it would be the same if you put
>   $mail->from(YOURMOM@LOL.com). The e-mail would still send, but your
>   domain name does not match the @ address.